# dynamically render toolstripmenuitem based on login status without disallows late binding error

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to set the Visible property on an array of toolstripmenuitems dynamically like so but am getting an error `Option strict on disallows late binding`

```
Public Class Main
  Dim mainMenuItems As Array = {fileItem, createItem, loginItem}
  Dim loggedInItems As Array = {logoutItem, processItem}
  Dim loggedIn As Boolean = False

  Private Sub loginClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLogin.Click
    Using loginDialog As New LoginDialog
      If loginDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        loggedIn = True
      End If
    End Using

    If loggedIn Then
      For Each item In mainMenuItems
        item.Visible = False
      Next
      For Each item In loggedInItems
        item.Visible = True
      Next
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be much appreciated

Comment: Don't `Dim ... As Array`. They should be `Dim mainMenuItems() As MenuItem` You can only use the properties and methods of a type if it is declared as that type. Otherwisr your items will be Object and Object doesn't have a `.Visible` property.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375405/option-strict-on-disallows-late-binding

Comment: I would do away with the arrays altogether. Set the `Tag` property of each item in the designer and then loop through all the items in the menu and hide or show based on that `Tag`. Alternatively, create your own derived class with a dedicated property and avoid using the `Tag`.